# dataclass with aiohttp - convert invalid values to int, float or str

Tags: python, aiohttp, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to use a dataclass object to pass to the params of the aiohttp get request, but aiohttp only accept `float`, `int` or `str` as type in the params since it's the job of the user to handle those cases.

Let's say I want the following conversions:

```
    True  -> 'True'
    False -> 'False'
    None  -> ''
```

How can I achieve that conversion without manually doing the conversion before the request?

Here an example script that explain what I want to achieve:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from typing import Optional
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json

@dataclass
class Params:
    a: bool
    b: str
    c: Optional[float] = None


async def main():

    params = Params(
        a = True,
        b = 'b',
    )

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('http://www.example.com', params=convert(params))) as r:
            print(await r.text())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `fields` method from dataclass, I can iterate throught the dataclass' fields and do the conversion according to the value:

```py
from dataclasses import fields

def convert(dc: dataclass, mapping=None):

    if mapping is None:
        mapping = {
            None: '',
            True: str(True),
            False: str(False),
        }

    def _convert(value):
        if value in mapping:
            return mapping[value]
        return value

    return { field.name: _convert(getattr(dc, field.name)) for field in fields(dc) }
```

Note that this doesn't work with nested dataclasses, but aiohttp doesn't handle them either.

Comment: you could do this inside the post_init off your dataclass

Comment: ideally, i dont want to modify the data type until I send the request. I want to keep the value as bool in the dataclass and not change the type of the field to string.

Comment: oh ok, then yeah, a converted makes sense

Answer (score 1):

`asdict` can be used with a dict factory like this:

```py
class ConvertDict(dict):

    mapping = {
        None: '',
        True: str(True),
        False: str(False),
    }

    @staticmethod
    def _convert(value):
        if value in ConvertDict.mapping:
            return ConvertDict.mapping[value]
        return value

    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__((k, self._convert(v)) for k, v in data)
```

Then, the convertion will be done like this:

```py
asdict(params, dict_factory=ConvertDict)
```